# KSoap2 Pass Sub Object

Tags: java, android, web-services

I have to call a web service in which web service is called by kSoap2 method, now in this one node is a sub object so how i can pass it.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:AddDataVersion2>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:object>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Data1>?</tem:Data1>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Data2>?</tem:Data2>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Data3>?</tem:Data3>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <tem:Data4>?</tem:Data4>
         <tem:object>
      </tem:AddDataVersion2>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

this sub object =  how to add data to object and add object to

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"tem:AddDataVersion2");
        request.addProperty("Data1", 1);
        request.addProperty("Data2", 2);
        request.addProperty("Data3", 3);
        request.addProperty("Data4", 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not put data into `addProperty()` method directly. Instead you need to add your data into `PropertyInfo` object and add that object to `SoapObject` as `property`. In your case -

**For Ex :**

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,"tem:AddDataVersion2");
PropertyInfo propertyInfo1= new PropertyInfo();
propertyInfo.setName("Data1");
propertyInfo.setValue("1");
propertyInfo.setType(String.class);

PropertyInfo propertyInfo2= new PropertyInfo();
propertyInfo.setName("Data2");
propertyInfo.setValue("2");
propertyInfo.setType(String.class);

PropertyInfo propertyInfo3= new PropertyInfo();
propertyInfo.setName("Data3");
propertyInfo.setValue("3");
propertyInfo.setType(String.class);

PropertyInfo propertyInfo4= new PropertyInfo();
propertyInfo.setName("Data4");
propertyInfo.setValue("4");
propertyInfo.setType(String.class);

request.addProperty(propertyInfo1);
request.addProperty(propertyInfo2);
request.addProperty(propertyInfo3);
request.addProperty(propertyInfo4);
```

Hope it will help :)